# Detecting if phonegap is loaded in Android native JAVA code

Tags: android, cordova

I need to detect from a native JAVA (non phonegap plugin) class if phonegap's web view has finished loading. Is this possible, or will I need to rely on structuring my code as a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution (tested and works).
It's a tricky workaround but does the job.

**Step 1:**
Create a new class in the same package as your MainActivity like this:

```
public class MyClass{
    private WebView appView;

    public MyClass(DroidGap gap, WebView view){
        appView = view;
    }

    public void onLoaded(){
        // This will be called when webview loaded
        System.out.println("WORKED!!");
    }
}
```

**Step 2:**
Add the following lines to the very end of onCreate() in your MainActivity:

```
MyClass ai = new MyClass(this, super.appView);
super.appView.addJavascriptInterface(ai, "MyClass");
```

It should look something like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

    MyClass ai = new MyClass(this, super.appView);
    super.appView.addJavascriptInterface(ai, "MyClass");
}
```

**Step 3:**
In your JavaScript code in assets/www add this:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    try{
        // Might throw an error but onLoaded() gets called correctly
        window.MyClass.onLoaded();
    }
    catch(e){
        console.error(e)
    }
});
```

**Important:** Make sure that cordova.js is correctly included in your index.html

This did the job for me.